# Put several matrices in a compact way

Tags: spacing, align, matrices

I would like to put a series of matrices so that they occupy less space on the sheet, since I have a space limit and I do not want to occupy too much.
The idea would be to group the matrices a1, a2 a3 and a4 in a column and another column with the matrices a01, a02, a03 and a04.
Then group half of the remaining matrices in the left column and the other half in the right column.
Any other type of organization that is eye-catching would also work for me.

```
\begin{equation}
a1= \begin{bsmallmatrix}
-R_{l}  &1/n  &0  &0  &-1 &0\\ 
-1/n  &-1/R_1  &-1/R_2  &0  &0 &0 \\ 
0 &0  &1/R_2  &0  &0  &-1/R_o \\ 
1 &0  &0  &-1/R_3  &-1/R_4  &0 \\ 
R_{gen} &0  &0  &1  &-1-R_{gen}/R_4  &0 \\ 
0 &1  &-1  &0  &0  &-1 
\end{bsmallmatrix}
;\smallskip
a01= \begin{bsmallmatrix}
L_{lk} &0    &0    &0   &0   &0 \\ 
0      &C_1  &C_2  &0   &0   &0 \\ 
0      &0    &-C_2 &0   &0   &C_{out}*\left ( 1+\frac{EsrC_o}{R_o} \right ) \\ 
0      &0    &0    &C_3 &C_4 &0  \\ 
0      &0    &0    &0   &R_{gen}*C_4   &0 \\ 
0      &0    &0    &0   &0   &C_{out}*EsrC_o 
\end{bsmallmatrix}
\label{eq:State A1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
b1= \begin{bsmallmatrix}
0&0&0&0&-1&0
\end{bsmallmatrix}^{T} 
; A1 = \frac{a_1}{a_{01}}
; B1= \frac{b_1}{a_{01}}
\label{eq:State B1}
\end{equation}

%Matrices del estado 2%
\begin{equation}
a2= \begin{bsmallmatrix}
-R_{l}  &0  &1/n  &0  &-1 &0\\ 
-1/n  &-1/R_1  &-1/R_2  &0  &0 &0 \\ 
1/n &0  &1/R_2  &0  &0  &-1/R_o \\ 
1 &0  &0  &-1/R_3  &-1/R_4  &0 \\ 
R_{gen} &0  &0  &1  &-1-R_{gen}/R_4  &0 \\ 
0 &1  &-1  &0  &0  &-1 
\end{bsmallmatrix}
;\smallskip
a02= \begin{bsmallmatrix}
L_{lk} &0    &0    &0   &0   &0 \\ 
0      &C_1  &C_2  &0   &0   &0 \\ 
0      &0    &-C_2 &0   &0   &C_{out}*\left ( 1+\frac{EsrC_o}{R_o} \right ) \\ 
0      &0    &0    &C_3 &C_4 &0  \\ 
0      &0    &0    &0   &R_{gen}*C_4   &0 \\ 
0      &0    &0    &0   &0   &C_{out}*EsrC_o 
\end{bsmallmatrix}
\label{eq:State A2}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
b2= \begin{bsmallmatrix}
0&0&0&0&-1&0
\end{bsmallmatrix}^{T}
; A2 = \frac{a_2}{a_{02}}
; B2= \frac{b_2}{a_{02}}
\label{eq:State B2}
\end{equation}

%Matrices del estado 3%
\begin{equation}
a3= \begin{bsmallmatrix}
-R_{l}  &0  &1/n  &-1  &0 &0\\ 
-1/n  &-1/R_1  &-1/R_2  &0  &0 &0 \\ 
1/n &0  &1/R_2  &0  &0  &-1/R_o \\ 
1 &0  &0  &-1/R_3  &-1/R_4  &0 \\ 
0 &0  &0  &1  &-1-R_{gen}/R_4  &0 \\ 
0 &1  &-1  &0  &0  &-1 
\end{bsmallmatrix}
;\smallskip
a03= \begin{bsmallmatrix}
L_{lk} &0    &0    &0   &0   &0 \\ 
0      &C_1  &C_2  &0   &0   &0 \\ 
0      &0    &-C_2 &0   &0   &C_{out}*\left ( 1+\frac{EsrC_o}{R_o} \right ) \\ 
0      &0    &0    &C_3 &C_4 &0  \\ 
0      &0    &0    &0   &R_{gen}*C_4   &0 \\ 
0      &0    &0    &0   &0   &C_{out}*EsrC_o 
\end{bsmallmatrix}
\label{eq:State A3}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
b3= \begin{bsmallmatrix}
0&0&0&0&-1&0
\end{bsmallmatrix}^{T}
; A3 = \frac{a_3}{a_{03}}
; B3= \frac{b_3}{a_{03}}
\label{eq:State B3}
\end{equation}

%Matrices del estado 4%
\begin{equation}
a4= \begin{bsmallmatrix}
-R_{l}  &1/n  &0  &-1  &0 &0\\ 
-1/n  &-1/R_1  &-1/R_2  &0  &0 &0 \\ 
0 &0  &1/R_2  &0  &0  &-1/R_o \\ 
1 &0  &0  &-1/R_3  &-1/R_4  &0 \\ 
0 &0  &0  &1  &-1-R_{gen}/R_4  &0 \\ 
0 &1  &-1  &0  &0  &-1 
\end{bsmallmatrix}
; \smallskip
a04= \begin{bsmallmatrix}
L_{lk} &0    &0    &0   &0   &0 \\ 
0      &C_1  &C_2  &0   &0   &0 \\ 
0      &0    &-C_2 &0   &0   &C_{out}*\left ( 1+\frac{EsrC_o}{R_o} \right ) \\ 
0      &0    &0    &C_3 &C_4 &0  \\ 
0      &0    &0    &0   &R_{gen}*C_4   &0 \\ 
0      &0    &0    &0   &0   &C_{out}*EsrC_o 
\end{bsmallmatrix}
\label{eq:State A4}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    b4= \begin{bsmallmatrix}
    0&0&0&0&-1&0
\end{bsmallmatrix}^{T}
    ; A4 = \frac{a_4}{a_{04}}
    ; B4= \frac{b_4}{a_{04}}
\label{eq:State B4}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! Please extend your code fragment to complete small document with your matrices. Please elaborate, what you mean with "compact way"

Answer (score 2):

You need wider lines to fit the big matrices.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
%Matrices del estado 1
a_1= \begin{bsmallmatrix}
-R_{l}  &1/n  &0  &0  &-1 &0\\ 
-1/n  &-1/R_1  &-1/R_2  &0  &0 &0 \\ 
0 &0  &1/R_2  &0  &0  &-1/R_o \\ 
1 &0  &0  &-1/R_3  &-1/R_4  &0 \\ 
R_{\mathrm{gen}} &0  &0  &1  &-1-R_{\mathrm{gen}}/R_4  &0 \\ 
0 &1  &-1  &0  &0  &-1 
\end{bsmallmatrix}
;\quad
a_{01}= \begin{bsmallmatrix}
L_{lk} &0    &0    &0   &0   &0 \\ 
0      &C_1  &C_2  &0   &0   &0 \\ 
0      &0    &-C_2 &0   &0   &C_{\mathrm{out}}\cdot  ( 1+\frac{\mathrm{EsrC}_o}{R_o}  ) \\ 
0      &0    &0    &C_3 &C_4 &0  \\ 
0      &0    &0    &0   &R_{\mathrm{gen}}\cdot C_4   &0 \\ 
0      &0    &0    &0   &0   &C_{\mathrm{out}}\cdot \mathrm{EsrC}_o 
\end{bsmallmatrix}
\label{eq:State A1}
\\
b_1= \begin{bmatrix} 0&0&0&0&-1&0 \end{bmatrix}^{T} 
;\quad A_1 = \frac{a_1}{a_{01}}
;\quad B_1= \frac{b_1}{a_{01}}
\label{eq:State B1}
\\[2ex]
%Matrices del estado 2
a_2= \begin{bsmallmatrix}
-R_{l}  &0  &1/n  &0  &-1 &0\\ 
-1/n  &-1/R_1  &-1/R_2  &0  &0 &0 \\ 
1/n &0  &1/R_2  &0  &0  &-1/R_o \\ 
1 &0  &0  &-1/R_3  &-1/R_4  &0 \\ 
R_{\mathrm{gen}} &0  &0  &1  &-1-R_{\mathrm{gen}}/R_4  &0 \\ 
0 &1  &-1  &0  &0  &-1 
\end{bsmallmatrix}
;\quad
a_{02}= \begin{bsmallmatrix}
L_{lk} &0    &0    &0   &0   &0 \\ 
0      &C_1  &C_2  &0   &0   &0 \\ 
0      &0    &-C_2 &0   &0   &C_{\mathrm{out}}\cdot  ( 1+\frac{\mathrm{EsrC}_o}{R_o}  ) \\ 
0      &0    &0    &C_3 &C_4 &0  \\ 
0      &0    &0    &0   &R_{\mathrm{gen}}\cdot C_4   &0 \\ 
0      &0    &0    &0   &0   &C_{\mathrm{out}}\cdot \mathrm{EsrC}_o 
\end{bsmallmatrix}
\label{eq:State A2}
\\
b_2= \begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0&0&-1&0
\end{bmatrix}^{T}
;\quad A_2 = \frac{a_2}{a_{02}}
;\quad B_2= \frac{b_2}{a_{02}}
\label{eq:State B2}
\\[2ex]
%Matrices del estado 3
a_3= \begin{bsmallmatrix}
-R_{l}  &0  &1/n  &-1  &0 &0\\ 
-1/n  &-1/R_1  &-1/R_2  &0  &0 &0 \\ 
1/n &0  &1/R_2  &0  &0  &-1/R_o \\ 
1 &0  &0  &-1/R_3  &-1/R_4  &0 \\ 
0 &0  &0  &1  &-1-R_{\mathrm{gen}}/R_4  &0 \\ 
0 &1  &-1  &0  &0  &-1 
\end{bsmallmatrix}
;\quad
a_{03}= \begin{bsmallmatrix}
L_{lk} &0    &0    &0   &0   &0 \\ 
0      &C_1  &C_2  &0   &0   &0 \\ 
0      &0    &-C_2 &0   &0   &C_{\mathrm{out}}\cdot  ( 1+\frac{\mathrm{EsrC}_o}{R_o}  ) \\ 
0      &0    &0    &C_3 &C_4 &0  \\ 
0      &0    &0    &0   &R_{\mathrm{gen}}\cdot C_4   &0 \\ 
0      &0    &0    &0   &0   &C_{\mathrm{out}}\cdot \mathrm{EsrC}_o 
\end{bsmallmatrix}
\label{eq:State A3}
\\
b_3= \begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0&0&-1&0
\end{bmatrix}^{T}
;\quad A_3 = \frac{a_3}{a_{03}}
;\quad B_3= \frac{b_3}{a_{03}}
\label{eq:State B3}
\\[2ex]
%Matrices del estado 4
a_4= \begin{bsmallmatrix}
-R_{l}  &1/n  &0  &-1  &0 &0\\ 
-1/n  &-1/R_1  &-1/R_2  &0  &0 &0 \\ 
0 &0  &1/R_2  &0  &0  &-1/R_o \\ 
1 &0  &0  &-1/R_3  &-1/R_4  &0 \\ 
0 &0  &0  &1  &-1-R_{\mathrm{gen}}/R_4  &0 \\ 
0 &1  &-1  &0  &0  &-1 
\end{bsmallmatrix}
;\quad 
a_{04}= \begin{bsmallmatrix}
L_{lk} &0    &0    &0   &0   &0 \\ 
0      &C_1  &C_2  &0   &0   &0 \\ 
0      &0    &-C_2 &0   &0   &C_{\mathrm{out}}\cdot  ( 1+\frac{\mathrm{EsrC}_o}{R_o}  ) \\ 
0      &0    &0    &C_3 &C_4 &0  \\ 
0      &0    &0    &0   &R_{\mathrm{gen}}\cdot C_4   &0 \\ 
0      &0    &0    &0   &0   &C_{\mathrm{out}}\cdot \mathrm{EsrC}_o 
\end{bsmallmatrix}
\label{eq:State A4}
\\
    b_4= \begin{bmatrix}
    0&0&0&0&-1&0
\end{bmatrix}^{T}
    ;\quad A_4 = \frac{a_4}{a_{04}}
    ;\quad B_4= \frac{b_4}{a_{04}}
\label{eq:State B4}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

I fixed several weak points: words should be upright and subscripts should be used consistently.

I have doubts about the meaning of `EscrO_o` and the other `_o` subscripts: should they be `_0` instead?

Consecutive equations should be treated with `gather` and I added some vertical space between the big blocks.

Finally, `\smallskip` inside a displayed equation doesn't do what you seem to expect. I added `\quad` after all semicolons.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Loading geometry to have more decent margins, and using the `alignat` environment, you can have this layout:
[image]

```
        \documentclass{article}
        \usepackage{mathtools}
        \usepackage{geometry}

        \begin{document}

        \begin{alignat}{2}
        a1 & = \begin{bsmallmatrix}
        -R_{l} &\frac{1}{n} &0 &0 &-1 &0\\
        -\frac{1}{n} &-\frac{1}{R_1} &-\frac{1}{R_2} &0 &0 &0 \\
        0 &0 &\frac{1}{R_2} &0 &0 &-\frac{1}{R_o} \\
        1 &0 &0 &-\frac{1}{R_3} &-\frac{1}{R_4} &0 \\
        R_\text{gen} &0 &0 &1 &-1-\frac{R_\text{gen}}{R_4} &0 \\
        0 &1 &-1 &0 &0 &-1
        \end{bsmallmatrix}
        ; & \qquad
        a01 & = \begin{bsmallmatrix}
        L_{lk} &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 \\
        0 &C_1 &C_2 &0 &0 &0 \\
        0 &0 &-C_2 &0 &0 &C_\text{out}*\left ( 1+\frac{EsrC_o}{R_o} \right ) \\
        0 &0 &0 &C_3 &C_4 &0 \\
        0 &0 &0 &0 &R_\text{gen}*C_4 &0 \\
        0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &C_\text{out}*EsrC_o
        \end{bsmallmatrix}
        \label{eq:State A1} \\
        %
        b1 & = \begin{bsmallmatrix}
        0&0&0&0&-1&0
        \end{bsmallmatrix}^{T}
        ; & A1 & = \frac{a_1}{a_{01}}
        ; \quad B1= \frac{b_1}{a_{01}}.
        \label{eq:State B1} \\[3ex]
        %Matrices del estado 2%
        a2 & = \begin{bsmallmatrix}
        -R_{l} &0 &1/n &0 &-1 &0\\
        -\frac{1}{n} &-\frac{1}{R_1} &-\frac{1}{R_2} &0 &0 &0 \\
        \frac{1}{n} &0 &\frac{1}{R_2} &0 &0 &-\frac{1}{R_o} \\
        1 &0 &0 &-\frac{1}{R_3} &-\frac{1}{R_4} &0 \\
        R_\text{gen} &0 &0 &1 &-1-\frac{R_\text{gen}}{R_4} &0 \\
        0 &1 &-1 &0 &0 &-1
        \end{bsmallmatrix}
        ; &
        a02 & = \begin{bsmallmatrix}
        L_{lk} &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 \\
        0 &C_1 &C_2 &0 &0 &0 \\
        0 &0 &-C_2 &0 &0 &C_\text{out}*\left ( 1+\frac{EsrC_o}{R_o} \right ) \\
        0 &0 &0 &C_3 &C_4 &0 \\
        0 &0 &0 &0 &R_\text{gen}*C_4 &0 \\
        0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &C_\text{out}*EsrC_o
        \end{bsmallmatrix}
        \label{eq:State A2} \\
        b2 & = \begin{bsmallmatrix}
        0&0&0&0&-1&0
        \end{bsmallmatrix}^{T}
        ; & A2 & = \frac{a_2}{a_{02}}
        ; \quad B2= \frac{b_2}{a_{02}}.
        \label{eq:State B2}\\[3ex]
        a3 & = \begin{bsmallmatrix}
        -R_{l} &0 &\frac{1}{n} &-1 &0 &0\\
        -\frac{1}{n} &-\frac{1}{R_1} &-\frac{1}{R_2} &0 &0 &0 \\
        \frac{1}{n} &0 &\frac{1}{R_2} &0 &0 &-\frac{1}{R_o} \\
        1 &0 &0 &-\frac{1}{R_3} &-\frac{1}{R_4} &0 \\
        0 &0 &0 &1 &-1-\frac{R_\text{gen}}{R_4} &0 \\
        0 &1 &-1 &0 &0 &-1
        \end{bsmallmatrix}
        ; &
        a03 & = \begin{bsmallmatrix}
        L_{lk} &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 \\
        0 &C_1 &C_2 &0 &0 &0 \\
        0 &0 &-C_2 &0 &0 &C_\text{out}*\left ( 1+\frac{EsrC_o}{R_o} \right ) \\
        0 &0 &0 &C_3 &C_4 &0 \\
        0 &0 &0 &0 &R_\text{gen}*C_4 &0 \\
        0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &C_\text{out}*EsrC_o
        \end{bsmallmatrix}
        \label{eq:State A3} \\
        b3 & = \begin{bsmallmatrix}
        0&0&0&0&-1&0
        \end{bsmallmatrix}^{T}
        ; & A3 & = \frac{a_3}{a_{03}}
        ; \quad B3= \frac{b_3}{a_{03}}.
        \label{eq:State B3} \\[3ex]
        %Matrices del estado 4%
        a4 & = \begin{bsmallmatrix}
        -R_{l} &\frac{1}{n} &0 &-1 &0 &0\\
        -\frac{1}{n} &-\frac{1}{R_1} &-\frac{1}{R_2} &0 &0 &0 \\
        0 &0 &\frac{1}{R_2} &0 &0 &-\frac{1}{R_o} \\
        1 &0 &0 &-\frac{1}{R_3} &-\frac{1}{R_4} &0 \\
        0 &0 &0 &1 &-1-\frac{R_\text{gen}}{R_4} &0 \\
        0 &1 &-1 &0 &0 &-1
        \end{bsmallmatrix}
        ; &
        a04 & = \begin{bsmallmatrix}
        L_{lk} &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 \\
        0 &C_1 &C_2 &0 &0 &0 \\
        0 &0 &-C_2 &0 &0 &C_\text{out}*\left ( 1+\frac{EsrC_o}{R_o} \right ) \\
        0 &0 &0 &C_3 &C_4 &0 \\
        0 &0 &0 &0 &R_\text{gen}*C_4 &0 \\
        0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &C_\text{out}*EsrC_o
        \end{bsmallmatrix}
        \label{eq:State A4} \\
            b4 & = \begin{bsmallmatrix}
            0&0&0&0&-1&0
        \end{bsmallmatrix}^{T}
            ; & A4 & = \frac{a_4}{a_{04}}
            ;\quad B4= \frac{b_4}{a_{04}}
        \label{eq:State B4}
        \end{alignat}

        \end{document}
```